# trouble with minimax tree in the CS50 tictactoe

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, tic-tac-toe, minimax

after watching https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:HarvardX+CS50AI+1T2020 (CS50 course) I was assigned to create an AI that could play tic-tac-toe via a minimax tree. However I'm having trouble to making the minimax function itself.

I do have some idea on how to create one (using the Action function repetitivley to create the tree, and checking it when putting the computer in the shoes of a Min or Max) but i'm not sure if I'm right and i'm not sure how to implement it well.

Here's my messy code (with comments so it's easier to read):

```
#this copies arrays so we don't have to do array_1 = array_2
def copyArr(input):
    out=[]
    for i in range(len(input)):
        out.append(input[i])
    return out
array=[]

#makes the board
def MakeArray():
    global array
    for i in range(9):
        array.append(" ")

#StyleArray prints the board out in a stylish way
def StyleArray(arr):
    return arr[0]+" | "+arr[1]+" | "+arr[2]+"\n"+"- - - - -\n"+arr[3]+" | "+arr[4]+" | "+arr[5]+"\n"+"- - - - -\n"+arr[6]+" | "+arr[7]+" | "+arr[8] + "\n"

#checks whose turn on the board it is to play
def player(s):
    number = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] != " ":
            number += 1
    if number%2 == 1:
        return "O"
    if number%2 == 0:
        return "X"
    return "there was a fatal issue bro"

#Action checks what actions are avalable with the given board
def Action(arr):
    actions=[]
    results=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        array_1=copyArr(arr)
        if arr[i] != "X":
            array_1[i]="O"
            if array_1 != arr:
                 results.append(array_1)
        else:
            array_1[i]=" "
    for i in range(len(results)):
        array_1=copyArr(results[i])
        #print(array_1)
        for x in range(len(array_1)):
            if array_1[x] == "X":
                array_1[x]=" "
        actions.append(array_1)
    return actions, results

#terminal checks whether a player has won yet, and returns it as a True or False. utility is IF someone won then what the corrosponding value would be(-1, 0, 1)
#-1 meaning that it lost 0 meaning a tie and 1 meaning a win
def terminal(s):
    winning_combinations = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
    ]
    for combination in winning_combinations:
        if s[combination[0]] == s[combination[1]] == s[combination[2]] and s[combination[0]] != " ":
            if s[combination[0]] == "O":
                utility = 1
            else:
                utility = -1
            return True, utility
    return False, 0
```

if anyone could help me I would be greatful. :P
~Jake

Comment: There is no need to create an actual tree. This site contains several posts with implementations of minimax in Python.

Comment: You don't create a tree, you use regression. This is discussed in the lecture. Review to see how `mimimax()` is implemented with regression using `max_value()` and `min_value()` functions.